# parse.com Client Push notifications are not received in windows phone when application is offline

Tags: parse-platform, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

I have followed the steps given in the document in parse.com, but the client side notifications are not received in windows phone when the app is offline. But if I send a Campaign push from parse.com it reaches fine even if the app is offline.

The client push works fine if my app is online. Also I have verified that my client push reaches parse.com and do not see any issues with the message content.

```
public App() {
ParseClient.Initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
this.Startup += async (sender, args) =>
{
    // This optional line tracks statistics around app opens, including push effectiveness:
    ParseAnalytics.TrackAppOpens(RootFrame);
    ParsePush.ToastNotificationReceived += (sender, args) =>
    {
      var json = ParsePush.PushJson(args);
      MessageBox.Show("Received a new notification");

    };
}
```